# how to i get the location data every 5 seconds from MAUI Android app( as foreground Service)

Tags: android, maui

I'm developing an app that needs to get the current location of the device every 5 seconds and sends it to the server. I use foreground service to run the location service. but after a while, the foreground service stops getting data.
I'm using  [Ms Geolocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/geolocation?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android) to get the data. is there any reason to stop getting location data after requesting it for a while? or

Comment: Many discussions of this topic can be found by googling `android app foreground service stops getting location data`. Two main causes: 1) Is the app showing any visible UI to user, while in foreground? If not, then you need to correctly tell Android OS you use foreground; then the foreground feedback will appear. 2) battery optimization: you might need to prompt user to disable power-saving for this app.